# rename file on Xcode 13

Tags: xcode

I want to rename a file displayed on the sidebar of Xcode.

I could successfully change a file name on editor pane by Right-click on the class name in the interface, choose Refactor->Rename. However, that has not worked for the name displayed on the side bar.

Could you help me out to change it.

environment:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwrhg.png)
Xcode 13

Comment: Can you rename the file by selecting it in the sidebar and pressing the Return key?